# PHP program that requires user to accept a string as a parameter and return the same string randomly capitalized characters

Tags: php, string

PHP program that requires user to accept a string as a parameter and return the same string randomly capitalized characters. Example: the input is “php script” may display “PHP SCRIPT”, “pHp ScriPT”, “PHP script” or “php SCRIPT”.

I don't really know what i'm doing actually.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Random Capitalized Character </h2>
<form action="Q5.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="input" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['input'])) echo $_POST['input']; ?>" /></p><input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

$name = "input"; 

$lowercaseTitle = strtolower($name);
$uppercaseTitle = strtoupper($name);
$ucTitleString = ucwords($lowercaseTitle && $uppercaseTitle);
echo "$ucTitleString";
?>
```

I would like to ask how to create this? already done this and that but results still no no.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Do you have any code or something you already done?

Comment: Please dont ask us to help you while your are in class and learn from a teacher. And dont post the Task here. Nobody will start a question with `Write a PHP program` when he ask for himself ;-) And next time show your code first.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions well this is my task but then teachers didn't teach us this one. Plus i'm not Programming student , because i'm Multimedia student. That's why i'm trying to reach any helps here , btw thanks ! :)

Comment: @chinmay i don't really understand what i'm doing , thanks but already edited so you can see the code.

Comment: You need [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and [strtolower, strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) functions, read, and try to use those functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a custom function to **randomly capitalized characters**:

```
    function randomCapitalize($input)
    {
        $output = '';

        foreach (str_split($input) as $c) {
            if (rand(0, 1) == 1) {
                $output .= strtoupper($c);
            } else {
                $output .= strtolower($c);
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

And you just need to `echo` with your string in parameter:

```
 echo randomCapitalize(“php script”);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Appreciate it so much! :) @Jouby